# Python Selenium Chrome : Open a new tab Ctrl + t ( BY KEYBOARD)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to automate this basic things with PYTHON:

- Open browser chrome
- Open new tab by keyboard ( Ctrl + t )

I only know how to open the browser now and search for a link :

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('location')

browser.get('https://google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, the most easy one is to use pyautogui module.

First of install pyautogui
then code is as follows:

```
import pyautogui
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome("c:\Webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")  #Location of driver in my case
browser.get('https://google.com/')

# To open a new tab
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','t')
```

Comment: i applied, it not given me any error but it's not working too ( nothing happens )

Comment: Error : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Comment: @SalmaMadini Please try the first one it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below line in your code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Comment: Try changing the element from 'body' to some other element and try. If still doesn't work, then 
try this 
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't') or browser.execute_script('''window.open("http://bings.com","_blank");''')